# Powershell Importing custom C# CMDlets, no available "ExportedCommands"

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, import-module

first question here :)

So I have to create a custom CMDLet for Powershell 2.0, using visual studio 2010 express.
I have followed this seemingly simple tutorial : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2010/03/08/how-to-create-a-powershell-2-0-module-and-cmdlet-with-visual-studio-2010-screencast-included.aspx

My code is almost the same (even tried copy pasting thier code) but after I call **Import-Module "path_to_dll"**

and then call **Get-Module**, i see my imported module, **but no ExportedCommands are available.**

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Binary     PowerShellCMDLetsLibrary  {}
```

C# Code:

```
namespace PowerShellCMDLetsLibrary
{
    [System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet(System.Management.Automation.VerbsCommon.Get,"RemedyXml")]
    public class Get_RemedyXml:System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet
    {
    [System.Management.Automation.Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
    public string TicketID;

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
    ...
    this.WriteObject(Result.InnerXml, true);
    }
```

Might be a blunder, I just can't see it

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump out @ me:

1. The TicketID is a field, not a Property.
2. The overnamedspaced attribution makes the code hard to read.

I suspect it's #1 , but I can't see enough past #2 to be sure.

Hope this Helps

Comment: I found the solution. 

Copied my dll from UNC networkpath to local c:\
And now the command shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if repost, but:

I found the solution. Copied my dll from UNC networkpath to local c:\ 
And now the command shows up.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this off a network or unc path , you must add the path to your .net trusts:

ie:

```
caspol -machine -addgroup 1. -url "file:\\\network\dir\\*" FullTrust  -n Uniquename
```

HTH,

Bob

Comment: As noted by the question's author, Import-Module loads Cmdlets when the module is stored locally but not when loaded from the network.  After granting FullTrust to the network directory, Import-Module finds the contained Cmdlets.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, it did work.  Then I tried setting my module up to work from a different share and that wasn't working, then I went back to the first share and can't get that working again, either.  I've used CasPol.exe -ResolvePerm to confirm that my assembly is, in fact, being granted FullTrust.  Very strange...

Comment: Figured it out.  I was using the 32-bit version of `caspol.exe` yet launching 64-bit instances of PowerShell.  Once I made the changes using the 64-bit version of `caspol.exe` it worked.  Not sure why `caspol.exe -resolveperm` indicated my assembly was unrestricted when I'd granted FullTrust to its network path using the *wrong* version of `caspol.exe`, but oh well.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [Code Access Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security) in .NET.  By default, an [assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assemblies-in-the-common-language-runtime) loaded from a network share executes with reduced privileges, whereas one loaded from local storage has no restrictions at all.  Unfortunately, the `Import-Module` cmdlet gives no indication that it failed to import the cmdlets within a module, even when called with the `-Verbose` parameter.

To change the set of permissions granted to a particular network location, use the [`caspol.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/tools/caspol-exe-code-access-security-policy-tool) utility to create a new code group for that location:

```
caspol.exe -machine -addgroup 1.2 -url "file://server/share/directory/*" FullTrust
```

The `1.2` in the above command refers to the `LocalIntranet` code group, which will be the new code group's parent.  The following command will show which code groups are defined, and can be used to display the group that you created:

```
caspol.exe -machine -listgroups
```

Note that on 32-bit Windows `caspol.exe` is located in `%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\CLR_VERSION\` (where, for PowerShell 2.0, *CLR_VERSION* is `v2.0.50727`), and on 64-bit Windows another copy is located in `%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\CLR_VERSION\`.  The 32- and 64-bit versions each have their own security configuration file (`CONFIG\security.config`), so you will need to make sure you apply each security change to both versions using their respective `caspol.exe`.

The following command can be used to display the permissions that will be granted to a particular assembly:

```
caspol.exe -resolveperm "//server/share/directory/assembly.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

I basically copied an pasted your code. I did a Get-Module ClassLibrary2. Also TicketID does work.

```
ModuleType Name                      ExportedCommands
---------- ----                      ----------------
Binary     ClassLibrary2             Get-RemedyXml



using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "RemedyXml")]
    public class Class1 : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)] 
        public string TicketID;

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject(TicketID);
        }
    }
}
```